# textfield focus in flash not working online

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

I have created a Flash CS5.5 movie. The set-up is a little game. The movie starts with one textfield and the user has to type a code. So the textfield has to have a focus. I do this with this code:

```
txtInput.stage.focus = txtInput;
```

And it works fine! But when i put my SWF in a default HTML-page (which is online), then the only thing that happens is my cursor pinging in the textfield, but i can't type anymore. I first have to click the textfield before i can type into it. So the focus is set right, but i can't type in my text field. 
Can anybody help me with my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think in the HTML you need to add focus to Flash first.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/give-keyboard-focus-embedded-movie.html